# Type confusion: A type is class, a variable and an object?

Tags: c#

I'm currently working through the Pluralsight C# 5.0 course, and I'm relatively new to programming.

I previously thought I understood the concept of Data Types on a basic level, Int/Array/Strings etc.
In this course it starts to introduce C#'s huge emphasis on Types, and creating your own custom types.

One of the course code snippets which I've included below, is refusing to sink in and I was hoping
someone could provide some clarity or a different way of thinking about it.

Program.cs:

```
GradeStatistics stats = book.ComputeStatistics();
```

GradeStatistics.cs:

```
namespace Grades
    {
        public class GradeStatistics
        {
            public GradeStatistics()
            {
                HighestGrade = 0;
                LowestGrade = float.MaxValue;
            }

            public float AverageGrade;
            public float HighestGrade;
            public float LowestGrade;
        }
    }
```

Grades:

```
public GradeStatistics ComputeStatistics()
        {
            GradeStatistics stats = new GradeStatistics();

            float sum = 0f;
            foreach (float grade in grades)
            {
                stats.HighestGrade = Math.Max(grade, stats.HighestGrade);
                stats.LowestGrade = Math.Min(grade, stats.LowestGrade);
                sum += grade;
            }

            stats.AverageGrade = sum / grades.Count;
            return stats;
        }
```

I'm finding it particularly difficult to understand what exactly GradeStatistics is.
In the course it is referred to as not only a class, but as a variable, and furthermore also
being returned as an object in Grades.

Any clarity is appreciated, as I'm finding it a little difficult to follow with all of the 
above terms being thrown around.

Comment: The question "what exactly is a type?" is surprisingly difficult to answer and even expert programmers differ. For my take on what a type is *not*, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/08/29/what-is-this-thing-you-call-a-quot-type-quot-part-one.aspx and then the follow-up saying what a type is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/07/what-is-this-thing-you-call-a-quot-type-quot-part-two.aspx

Comment: I note also that you might be having difficulty with this particular class because it is really not a very well designed class. Do not use `GradeStatistics` as an exemplar of good class design, because it is pretty bad.

Comment: If you are having difficulty with understanding *variables*, that is easier. *A variable is a mutable storage location that contains a value*. Every variable is associated with a *type* that restricts what values can be stored in the variable. (In *most* situations the type of a variable that is known *to the compiler* and the type of the variable *at runtime* are the same, but in some rare conditions they can be different; you should not have to worry about this detail for now.)

Comment: I understand variables, but Types I am finding difficult to grasp.  As a beginner it sort of feels like they can be everything and it's somewhat overwhelming.

Comment: Thanks for the links to your blog posts, they look like just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GradeStatistics` is a class, from this declaration:

```
public class GradeStatistics
```

`stats` is a variable of type `GradeStatistics`, from this declaration:

```
GradeStatistics stats = new GradeStatistics();
```

The return type of `ComputeStatistics` is `GradeStatistics`, from this declaration:

```
public GradeStatistics ComputeStatistics()
```

So, it's a class. It is being used to declare a variable with a particular type, and it is used to declare what a particular method will return, an object of the type.

If it helps, you can sort of think of a type as a blueprint. You can have a blueprint of a house. This will tell you that "if you had a house", this is what it would look like.

When you construct an instance of the type, ie. build the house, you get an instance. It has a type (it follows the blueprint), but it may be different from other instances, having other property values (like the color of the paint used, or the style of doors).

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response / taking the time to explain it in a clear way. Really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Or, fairly importantly, the location, in that it might be one of a number of similar houses in a road, all built to the same blueprint, and indistinguishable from one another other than where they are.

Answer (score 3):

First, **GradeStatistics** is a **Class**.

Second, it is not referred as a variable anywhere. But **stats** is actually a variable of type **GradeStatistics** in this line.

```
GradeStatistics stats = new GradeStatistics();
```

Third, **ComputeStatistics** is a function which return **GradeStatistics**.

And if you have read OOP than you should know that any object of any class type can be returned as a function return value.

Comment: Apologies for my lack of clarity in terms of the variable reference.  It was merely referenced in the course slides as a variable of type GradeStatistics which threw me off a little.

Answer (score 2):

GradeStatics is a class by definition.  When you use the new keyword you are creating an instance of that class (an object) which you can pass around or assign it to a variable.

So your snippets above, GradeStatistics is defined as a class in the gradestatics.cs file.  Grades.cs creates an instance of this class in the computestatics method and assigns it to the stats variable which is populated in yhat method and then returned

Answer (score 2):

`GradeStatistics` is a class. From this snippet:

```
    public class GradeStatistics
    {
        public GradeStatistics()
        {
            HighestGrade = 0;
            LowestGrade = float.MaxValue;
        }

        public float AverageGrade;
        public float HighestGrade;
        public float LowestGrade;
    }
```

However, in the method `ComputeStatistics`, the return type is `GradeStatistics`, not `void` as you are probably accustomed to. This means that `ComputeStatistics` returns a `GradeStatistics`. Lets look at an easier example.

Suppose we have a class `Foo`. It is constructed like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public Foo()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
}
```

Now we can create `Foo`s and access them normally.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.a = 4;
foo.b /= 2;
```

Now suppose we want to do this, except many times, so we create a method.

```
public Foo IncrementFoo(int amount, int divideBy)
{
    Foo obj = new Foo();
    obj.a = amount;
    obj.b /= divideBy;
    return obj;
}
```

This method creates a new object of type `Foo`, and returns it. You can then use this code like:

```
Foo newFoo = IncrementFoo(4, 2);
//foo == newFoo
```

I would recommend you read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx), especially about return types.

Note: In this case, it may be better to write an [Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), especially if we want to modify a single instance of a `Foo`, but we don't want to get into that. Also if we were really wanting to create a new instance of `Foo` like that, it would be better to use a constructor.

Comment: Another fantastic explanation, thank you :). I'll have a read through the links you've provided too.

Comment: @orangey No problem! I think msdn is an excellent resource, especially for documentation